# How to convert fillable pdf to regular pdf using python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to save fillable pdf as regular pdf. In adobe, you can print the pdf to "Adobe pdf" printer. How to do that in the python 3?

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do: [mre]

Comment: @Patrick Artner Thanks, Patrick.Yes, i realize this question is too general. I have tried a few solutions and they did not work. I will open new questions about the issue i have. Again thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research and found a way to do this. Maybe this is not the best way, but it works for me. I hope someone could come up with a better way.

What i did was first convert the fillable pdf to word, then convert the word document back to pdf. If i convert fillable pdf to html/csv, i lost a lot of information and I couldn't figure out why. It worked well if i converted the pdf to word or pptx.

Here is the code i used:

```
import win32com.client, win32com.client.makepy, os, winerror, pandas as pd, errno, re
from win32com.client.dynamic import ERRORS_BAD_CONTEXT
import win32com.client as win32  
import time 
import sys
import comtypes.client

# convert pdf to docx
ERRORS_BAD_CONTEXT.append(winerror.E_NOTIMPL)

win32com.client.makepy.GenerateFromTypeLibSpec('Acrobat')
adobe = win32com.client.DispatchEx('AcroExch.App')
avDoc = win32com.client.DispatchEx('AcroExch.AVDoc')

src = r'C:\Users\test.pdf'
ret = avDoc.Open(src, src)
assert(ret)   
pdDoc = avDoc.GetPDDoc()
jObject = pdDoc.GetJSObject()
word_file = src.replace('.pdf','.docx')
if os.path.exists(word_file):
    os.remove(word_file)
    open(word_file,'w').close()      
jObject.SaveAs(word_file, "com.adobe.acrobat.docx")
pdDoc.Close()
avDoc.Close(True)
del pdDoc

#convert word document to pdf 
word =  comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
word.Visible = False
time.sleep(3)
wdFormatPDF = 17
doc = word.Documents.Open(word_file)
out_file = src.replace('.pdf','tempt.pdf')
doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```